# How do I set up to display an error message in Android Xamarin?(looking to make it work like txtError.Text = "Error found")

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on a school project and I am getting an exception "Null Exception" message. 
What I was looking to get as a behavior is:
If I click Save button from my "Add Item" screen, I should get a message that it was either successful or not. I tried applying breakpoints but it just gives me the same message. I was told that it is most likely that the code I indicated in the comment is failing but unsure what to do next.
Below is my AddItem activity code behind

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AddItem);

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.saveButton).Click += OnSaveClick;
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cancelButton).Click += OnCancelClick;

        // Create your application here
    }

    void OnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        long countCheck;
        //Retrieve the values the uesr entered into the UI

        string name = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nameInput).Text;
        int count = int.Parse(FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.countInput).Text);

        var intent = new Intent();

        //Load the new data into an Intenet for transport back to the Activity that started this one.

        intent.PutExtra("ItemName", name);
        intent.PutExtra("ItemCount", count);

        //Send the resuylt code and dataaa back(this does not end the current Activity)



        SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);

        //End the current Activity
        Finish();

    }

    void OnCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //End the current Activity.
        //The Result Code will default to Result.Canceled.
        Finish();
    }
```

This is my MainActivity code behind where I was trying to set the message but it's giving me an exceptions error instead.

```
public static List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Pre-Load with some sample data for convenience.

        Items.Add(new Item("Milk", 2));
        Items.Add(new Item("Crackers", 1));
        Items.Add(new Item("Apples", 5));

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.itemsButton).Click += OnItemsClick;
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.addItemButton).Click += OnAddItemClick;
        FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.aboutButton).Click += OnAboutClick;

    }
    void OnItemsClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //User the standard technique to start an activity: create an Intent and then pas it to StartACtivity.
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ItemsActivity));

        StartActivity(intent);
    }

    void OnAddItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The AddItem Activity will return the Name and Count of the newly added item.

        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(AddItemActivity));

        //Use StartActivityForResult so you are notified when the AddItem Activity Completes.
        //The parameter '100' is the request code that lets you identify which Activity is sending your results;
        //The value '100' is arbitrary, it has no meaning to Android.
        StartActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }
    void OnAboutClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Use the convenience method to start an Activity without creating an Intent.
        StartActivity(typeof(AboutActivity));
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        //base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        //A requestCode of 100 indicates this result is from the AddItem Activity.
        //The resultCode of OK means the user touched the SAVE button and not the CANCEL button.
        //The value for the new item are stored in the Intent Extras.
        if(requestCode == 100 && resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            string name = data.GetStringExtra("ItemName");
            int count = data.GetIntExtra("ItemCount", 0);
            long countCheck;
            //This adds the new item to the IItems,
            //public static List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
            //Created as a global(public) variable at the top of this page.
            if(MainActivity.Items.Exists(x => x.Name == name))
            {
               // FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvMessage).Text = "Item already exist in the list.";
            }


            else
            {
                MainActivity.Items.Add(new Item(name, count));
               // FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvMessage).Text = "Item was added in the list.";
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You mention that you are getting an exception twice, but you haven't bothered to tell us what the specific exception is.  That's highly relevant information.  It would also help if you can tell us which specific line of code causes the exception.

Comment: Hi Jason,Thank you for responding. It was this one:

Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

It was from this line when trying to add a non-existing item.

       FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvMessage).Text = "Item was added in the list.";

Comment: most likely FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvMessage) is failing, causing the null ref.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code below instead and it worked. :)

**Toast.MakeText(this, "Company already exist.", ToastLength.Long).Show();**